# 'gitlab-runner' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using Windows 10 and installed gitlab-runner using the [Gitlab's doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html).

After a successful installation and registration, I try to leave the folderI used to install (`C:\Gitlab-Runner` in my instance) and try to run `gitlab-runner`. I get the response: `'gitlab-runner' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I am able to run without issue in the `C:\Gitlab-Runner` folder, but nowhere else.

Based on the documentation and tutorials I looked at, I wouldn't expect this behavior; am I supposed to?

Answer (score 5):

Did you check to ensure that it was added to The windows environment. You will likely need to update the path variable to include the path that you are using to run the command.

On windows, you add to the PATH variable with the following steps (yanked from google [search](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=windows+environment+variables) page):

> On the Windows taskbar, right-click the Windows icon and select System.

> In the Settings window, under Related Settings, click Advanced system settings. ...

> On the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables. ...
> Click New to create a new environment variable.

Once you've added `C:/Gitlab-runner/` to `PATH`, I believe you should be able to invoke with `gitlab-runner`.

The only thing I'll add is that, for setting `PATH`,  the last step above is most likely unnecessary, as there will already be a variable named PATH with a list of directories stored in it. Just click *EDIT* and add your directory to the end of the list. Be sure to add the separator that is used for the others (I believe it's a semicolon on Windows...)

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I need to call `C:/Gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner` rather than just `gitlab-runner` in other directories.

Comment: Calling the program with it full installation path isn't the way to go, the answer of @Nate T is the right way, you simply need to update your `PATH` Environment Variable.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the name of the exe is correct in the folder C:\GitLab-Runner

In my situation, I have the gilab-runner.exe.exe, there was an extra .exe in the file name though its not showing in the directory.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ravat.png)